# Eclipse RCP - what is the prefered way to change part?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

Each plugin can define its own content (via `PartDescriptor`) that should be added to specific location in my application (into `PartStashContainer`).
There could be always just one `Part` from plugins visible in that `PartStashContainer`.

I can't find what is the preferred way how to achieve this. Should i somehow replace the currently visible `Part` with the new `Part` from plugin? Or just setup somehow the content of already visible `Part` (maybe via `setContributionUri`?).

I looked at `EPartService`. It looks it can instantiate `Part` according to `PartDescriptor`, but it has just some methods to make new `Part` visible. I need to add the new `Part` into existing `PartStashContainer` and possibly remove the old `Part`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EPartService` and `EModelService` for this.

If you are only going to have one instance of a part with a particular id you can use a 'Part' in the application model as a child of the 'PartStack' and just mark it as 'not rendered'. If you want to create multiple parts with the same id you can use a 'PartDescriptor'.

If you have a 'Part' in your application model marked as 'not rendered' you can show it like this:

```java
partService.showPart("part id", PartState.ACTIVATE);
```

If you want to create a part from a 'PartDescriptor' and place it in a part stack use:

```java
@Inject
MApplication app;


MPart part = partService.createPart("part descriptor id");

MPartStack stack = modelService.find("part stack id", app);

stack.getChildren().add(part);

partService.showPart(part, PartState.ACTIVATE);
```

To hide a part use:

```java
MPart part = partService.findPart("part id");

partService.hidePart(part);
```

Comment: but how eclipse know where i want to show that part? (in PartStashContainer). It looks like you are not passing any info about it to showPart call.

Comment: Sorry, added PartDescriptor example

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know! But `PartService.ACTIVATE` in your upper example needs to be changed into `PartState.ACTIVATE`